# How do I prevent access to the Items property in TCustomListView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a custom component I am creating which is derived from `TCustomListView`.

I do not need the `Items` property publishing or been accessible by code at runtime, as my custom component will be handling the populating and accessing of items.

I am aware of `UnlistPublishedProperty` which can be included in the `Register` procedure of your components. So with that in mind, I tried:

```
UnlistPublishedProperty(TMyListView, 'Items');
```

From what I understand the above only makes the property hidden from the Object Inspector, and so by code `MyListView1.Items` is still present.

How may I make the `Items` property (or any property I guess) a non visible, non accessible property to the user, yet still accessible by my component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `UnlistPublishedProperty` to arrange for a property not to be published. You can simply choose not to publish the property.

To hide it from code, as well the designer, you are out of luck. You might try this:

```
....
private
  property Items;
....
```

But it has no effect. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members):

> You can increase the visibility of a property in a descendent class by redeclaring it, but you cannot decrease its visibility.

Frankly if you want your control not to expose this property, you should not start from `TCustomListView`. Perhaps you need to encapsulate rather than inherit.

Comment: Ditto. Encapsulation would seem to be the way forward here.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on `encapsulate rather than inherit.`? What exactly do you mean by this, go further down the chain and build my component around `TCustomListControl` for example?

Comment: Sorry I understand the concept of encapsulation, I just meant I was unsure on encapsulating what exactly, you mean as Daniel said and essentially have an inner listview?

Answer (score 3):

For derived classes you can only increase the visibility of properties, but not decrease. Since the Items property is public in `TCustomListView` there is no way to hide it from the user of your component.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible.

There are two workarounds that come close:

1. Wrap the ListView Control within your own control (e.g. you create a control which internally contains a list control). The inner control is aligned to the client area and doesn't use any frames/border etc. Declare properties you wish to be public/published on the outer control. Properties for frame etc should be applied to the outer control, other properties should be forwarded to the inner ListView control
2. Create your own "ListView" control (which internally forwards to the WinAPI ListView control). You can copy pretty much everything of the VCL "TCustomListView" control and use protected on Items instead. (If you just USE this control, that shouldn't be a problem. However you shouldn't create a 3rd part library with it due to copyright issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can raise an Exception in the Items getter telling the programmer his fault, and create a new private property to store your list contents...

and override all methods to reference correctly the new right prop

Comment: That would be, err, surprising for the code writer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I may have solved my own problem. To do this, I created a new class, named `TMyListViewItems`.

From my component derived from `TCustomListView`, I have in the protected field my `Items` property which is the class I described above.

A snippet of the class structures would look something like this:

```
  { TMyListViewItems }
  TMyListViewItems = class
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

{ TMyListView }
  TMyListView = class(TCustomListView)
  private
    FItems: TMyListViewItems;
  protected
    property Items: TMyListViewItems read FItems;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    // publish default listview type properties if needed here..
    property Align;
    property BevelEdges;
    property BevelInner;
    property BevelKind;
    property BevelOuter;
    property BorderStyle;
    property Color;
    property Font;
    property HideSelection;
    property IconOptions;
    property MultiSelect;
    property ParentColor;
    property ParentFont;
    property TabStop;
  end;
```

Tthe `Items` property is no longer visible or accessible at designtime or runtime which was my main goal.

The only drawback I have discovered is anyone could typecast as a `TListView` or `TCustomListView` and the original `Items` property is back, but maybe I should not worry about that?

```
TListView(MyListView1).Items.Add.Caption := 'test';
```

Comment: You are trying too hard

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I now understand, im trying to take a ready made component and chop bits away that I dont need, and right now it seems completely wrong. Better rethink my whole approach to meet my needs

Answer (score -2):

You can use final to prevent descendent classes to override any of your methods. And if you declare that method as strict private that method won't be shown by Code Insight for in any descendent classes. Not sure if this also works with properties

> The Delphi compiler also supports the concept of final virtual method.
>   When the keyword final is applied to a virtual method, no descendent
>   class can override that method. Use of the final keyword is an
>   important design decision that can help document how the class is
>   intended to be used. It can also give the compiler hints that allow it
>   to optimize the code it produces.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked, as the `TCustomListView.Items` are already a public property. You can't then change it to lower visibility in a descendant and add `final` to hide the public `Items`.