# Prevent Typecasting which could reveal hidden properties?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

This question relates to an earlier question I asked: [How do I prevent access to the Items property in TCustomListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509923/how-do-i-prevent-access-to-the-items-property-in-tcustomlistview)

I posted my answer in the question linked above. Basically I tricked my `TMyCustomListView` derived component into using a different `Items` class which is protected and so is not visible or accessible at designtime or runtime.

I discovered a weakness though with this which is you could still typecast it to reveal the original listview `Items` property.

`TListView(MyListView1).Items.Add.Caption := 'test';`

I think it is unlikely that any potential user of my component would know the component is derived from `TMyCustomListView`, and whether they would need to typecast as a listview. But because I would prefer no access at all to the original listview `Items` property as the user would have no need or benefit to access it anyway, my newest question on the subject is whether or not it is possible to stop my component from been typecasted?

Thank you.

Comment: I would think users of your component would be developers. Better implement some sane design and leave the rest to them. If they don't need to hack item captions, they won't do that. If they somehow need to do that, why not let them hack. BTW, they would probably know how to find out *class parent*.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz my component is going to be like a animation editor where each item is an individual frame of the animation which is why the standard listview items property serves no purpose to other developers as I would handle the item side of things but would provide functions to access the frames anyway. I just wanted a component derived from a listview type control without the published properties it offers if that makes any sense.

Comment: What are the consequences if somebody manipulates the control in a way you don't support? Presumably, the animation won't be edited properly. That's a self-limiting problem. When consumers of your code find that things break when they use the control in an unsupported way, they'll either stop doing that, or they'll send you a patch that fixes the problem.

Comment: Looking at your prior question, I personally wouldn't go this route for this type of project. This seems like something which calls for a non-visual event driven component, and let your consumers implement their own GUI. What if someone wants to draw these images in a grid rather than a list view? What if they apply VCL Styles to their app, and the drawing you do does not follow their desired style? You shouldn't force people to use this visual control, unless you're extremely confident it covers every single possible scenario desired or required.

Comment: So your question here is basically "I decided on the absolute wrong way to solve a problem. Now how can I prevent people from taking advantage of the poor design decision I made?"

Comment: @KenWhite to be honest the chances of anyone ever using a component I make are close to zero. It is also worth mentioning I use Delphi for hobby purposes and mostly personal projects therefore please dont be negative towards what you call `poor design decision`. I realise now, and especially having read Jerry Dodge's comments that indeed it is a bad choice from my side. However it is not always obvious to me from the beginning, I dont usually realise I make bad choices until it is too late. I can now see what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

The whole point of inheritance is that subclasses must look like their ancestors. You can only add functionality - not remove it.

So, no cannot do what you're trying to do.

However with a little work, you can achieve a suitable encapsulation effect. You need to use composition instead of inheritance. (Suggestion: Do some research on "favour composition over inheritance".)

---

### Long Answer

If standard list view functionality serves no purpose to your component's users, then you can't really say that your component **is-a** list view. And **is-a** relationships is exactly what inheritance represents.

There are basically 2 ways to reuse code when working with objects:

- Inheriting from other classes: Which provides *all* the functionality in the ancestor classes. (Emphasis on all, because you even get functionality you don't want.)
- Using other objects: Where you hold a reference to another object and ask it to do work for you.

So instead of inheriting from a list view, consider rather using composition. The approach is very much like your own answer in your other question, just change the ancestor that you inherit from.

```
TMyCustomListView = class(TComponent)
private
  FListView: TListView;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;

constructor TMyCustomListView .Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FListView := TListView.Create(Self);
end;
```

Of course you'll find a whole bunch of features you want your list view to support that are already supported by `TListView`. Any such features you want to expose, you simply redirect to the internal list view. E.g.

```
procedure TMyCustomListView.AddItem(Item: String; AObject: TObject);
begin
  FListView.AddItem(Item, AObject);
end;
```

It turns out that because you're no longer inheriting, you're not expected to support list view's interface. So you're now free to make changes better suited to your component.

```
procedure TMyCustomListView.AddItem(AItemCaption: String;
    AObject: TMySpecialListViewObject; AItemHint: String);
begin
  //By forcing a specific kind of object to be added to your list view,
  //you know that anything added will be of an appropriate type.
  //Meaning that you can rely on using TMySpecialListViewObject
  //attributes in other places in your component.

  FListView.AddItem(Item, AObject);

  //Of course you can also do other things before or after adding to
  //the internal list view.
end;
```

#### Pros and Cons

Yes, quite obviously it is more work to use composition instead of inheritance:

- You don't automatically get the functionality of your internal object.
- You have to explicitly add what you want, redirecting calls to the internal object.
- You may need to intercept events to keep track of what's happening to the internal object.
- Some things may prove trickier to support if the your internal object doesn't expose everything you need. (This is especially true of VCL classes where many share the same unit and private members can be accessed similar to "friend" classes.)

But the advantages are:

- As with point 2 in the disadvantages: you have to explicitly add what you want. But in this case meaning you don't sit with things you don't want.
- Better encapsulation.
- Your class is easier to use because it has less methods/properties for a user to understand.
- In the long run your code will be more maintainable because you won't have to worry about someone using your class 'incorrectly'.
- Your classes tend to be more 'light-weight' because they aren't bloated with unused functionality.
- Light-weight classes are easier to test.

These advantages are basically why it's considered a good design practice to "favour inheritance over composition".

But as with all things in software development: you have to weigh up the pros and cons and choose which is best for each situation. Sometimes even though one type should really inherit from another, you may choose to go ahead and do so in any case.

#### Side Notes

In the example I demonstrated inheriting from `TComponent`. However, if you want to allow others to interact with your component as a `TWinControl` or `TControl`, you'll have to change the inheritance accordingly.

If you inherit from `TWinControl`, you'll need to decide what win control functionality to redirect to the internal list view, and the most appropriate way to do so.

E.g. You might override `CreateWindowHandle` to simply set your handle to that of the internal list view. Or you might go with full blown message handling and decide which messages you'll pass on to the internal object.

I won't go into more detail here, as this answer is long enough already.

Comment: +1, except for your "advantage": `Your classes tend to be more 'light-weight' because they aren't bloated with unused functionality.` - in fact, it's not necessarily light-weight. May be a mix-up of terminology, but light-weight would mean consuming less memory, while in fact this would consume the same and even more memory as the original class, because you still have a full instance of it. That being said, a third alternative, although exhausting, would be to re-create it by copying the original class' source and modifying it, if that source is available of course.

Comment: @JerryDodge the problem with copying the original delphi source as pointed out before is likely going to be some kind of copyright infringement, though a good idea and one I had thought of it may be too much for what I want. I do think going non visual may be the way to go, and possibly then making a separate viewer control similar to listview.

Comment: Just going to add a final comment here for everyone in case my intentions were not understood clearly. The reason I wanted to remove the standard items property from been accessible from my component derived from TCustomListView is because my component would handle the populating of items and provide functions for retrieving items etc. Because it was essentially a list of items with image indexes in vsIcon mode the component was to be like an animation editor, any user would need not care about the standard Items property for these reasons because it would no longer matter to them.

Answer (score 4):

*Every* potential user of your component could know that it's derived from `TMyCustomListView` because it says so right in the source file you include in your distribution. (And if you don't include the source, then first, shame on you, and second, they can just inspect `ClassParent`.)

But don't worry about that. It's not your job to keep everything hidden for other developers. Think about it: *You're* a developer; do *you* want everything hidden from you? Of course not. When you're using someone else's code (including Embarcadero's), you sometimes conclude that you know better how to solve your problems than the original authors, and you want access to the things that will let you solve your problem. Likewise, consumers of your code will sometimes know better than you. It's arrogant to assume that your code accounts for all possible uses.

The need to type-cast is a code smell. Anyone who needs to type-cast your objects to use them will *know* they're doing something sketchy, but if they do it anyway, you can assume it's with the understanding that it's not the ideal solution, and that it might break in some later release of your code. When you release a new version, don't make changes to your internals to intentionally break existing code, but at the same time, don't worry about making legitimately necessary changes to your internals to make the rest of your product better.

It should be your goal to ensure that consumers of your code don't *need* to do sketchy things just to solve their problems. If they do, then pay attention, because those are clearly places where your customers' needs aren't being met.

Ultimately, there's no way to hide everything from other developers. Present what you can with a good interface, and don't worry too much about somebody messing with the internals.

Comment: I agree with everything you have said but my intentions are more as not to confuse other users. If they are trying to access the original listview items property it would be no use to them which is why I try to hide it. Maybe I am trying too hard to hide that property, in fact I am probably trying to hard to change the listview style control.

Comment: @Blobby Take a look at some of the source which ships with Delphi. For example, `Application.Free`. Clearly no one is supposed to do that, so people just don't do it. I see no reason to completely restrict users from doing this. Sure, I could drive my car off a cliff. Does that mean you're going to build a wall just in case I try to?

Comment: If users are fumbling around like that, then you haven't adequately documented and demonstrated how to use your control. I agree that you're trying too hard to solve problems that haven't really presented themselves are problems yet. It's good that you're thinking about potential problems, but right now, you're assigning more weight to them than they deserve. I'm sure you have other things you could focus on instead (like a demo program, or a collection of recipes for using your control).

Comment: @RobKennedy see my comment above in response to Ken White. This is by no means a component even close to been released and likely will not be as I am just not a good enough developer to see things through to the end. I am a hobbyist user of Delphi and are no where near fluent or skilled as the majority of users around here which is why most simple and basic things can be rather trivial to me, and as you pointed out I am trying too hard thinking of potential problems that are probably just slowing me down. This is the reason I paticularly dislike downvoters to others with simple questions.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to remove a visible member in a descendant class.  If you really want to present "something that looks like an X but without the Y property," the simplest way to do this would be to create a new class that wraps an X and exposes most of its members with simple pass-through methods.

Comment: Indeed, although that might violate the "principle of least astonishment", because people expect to be able to access something like Items on a listview or similar class and might be "astonished" that it is missing.